# Use method name 'set' in thrift defintion

Tags: types, thrift, masking

I want to define a method `set()` within my thrift definition:

```
 string set(1:string key, i32 secondsToLive)
```

I know `set` ist a predefined [thrift type](https://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/#_types). Is there any way to mask the method name to tell thrift that this is just a name and has nothing to do with the data type `set`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrift does not support this feature. The solution is not use the reserved language keyword. Thrift is a cross-language tool, and `set` is indeed a keyword in some of them.